# Schedule the copy of a document to a network location

Tags: powershell, copy-and-paste, file

I'm looking to copy a document to a network location on a scheduled basis. Anyone have a best practice on how to do that? I thought I could write a work flow, but since I want to copy to a non-SharePoint location, I didn't see any options with SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Can this copy folder and its contents to file share from document library?

Answer (score 2):

I think using PowerShell script with windows sheduler is very usefull way.
UPD. Question was interesting to me and i solved it.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint
$spFile = $web.GetFile("/Documents/folder/document.docx")
$target = "\\networkshare\document.docx"
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($target,$spFile.OpenBinary())
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I'm curious if anyone has done something similar and might be willing to share the few lines of code

Comment: Question was interesting to me and i solved it.

Comment: I've done it via Nintex workflow, but nothing programmatic like that.

Comment: Nintex isn't free and this code doesn't need any additional tools. But it's up2u =)